# Sending formatted bash array as an e-mail to Outlook

Tags: arrays, bash, email, outlook

I'm trying to automate some file consistency/quality checks - basically I have multiple text files, that are being checked by bash script (for missing headers, correct filename patterns etc.) and I would like to add all bad filenames to a bash array and send it via e-mail to other devs to notify them about bad files. I'm using array because I don't want to send separate e-mail for each faulty text file, but the problem is, that all text file names in e-mail are thrown in one pile - I would like to add a newline after each item for readability. E-mail client is Outlook 2013. 
P.S. Writing file names to a file and send as an attachment is a backup plan

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't Outlook mangling the file?

Comment: Would you mind showing some code?

Comment: Looks like the the problem is in my bash script, because I get the same output on Gmail client. What's the proper way to add newline after appending an item to an array? Currently I'm doing it like `my_arr+=("$txtfile\n")`. I will provide more detailed code sample later if needed () . Also @Michael, I'm not sending the files, I'm sending file names, that I get from iterating through a directory

Comment: Try this: `echo ${arr[*]} | xargs -n1`.